# How to change characters in specific location using shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file which I wish to programmatically alter to set different parameters:

```
$ cat ex.dat 
line 1 
here's another line
this is the number I want to change --> 1e-11
more lines
```

I want to change `1e-11` to the values `5.`, `10`, and `20.`. Something like this:

```
mkd () 
{
    mkdir $1;
    cd $1
}
for j in  1 2 3 4 5 ; do
     mkd WS$j
     cp ../ex.dat .
     sed -ie '3s/1e-11/${j}./' ex.dat
     cd ..
done
```

My approach isn't working. How can I replace `1e-11` with `$j`'s value?

```
$ cat WS3/ex.dat
line 1 
here's another line
this is the number I want to change --> ${j}.
more lines
```

Comment: What do you mean *"isn't working"*? Explaining the specific behavior is helpful for others...

Comment: _Double-quote_ the `sed` script to ensure that `${j}` is expanded by the shell. Also `-ie` will create a backup file with suffix `e`, perhaps you meant to use `-i -e`, or, simply `-i`. Also, double-quote all your shell-variable references in general, to prevent unwanted modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double quotes to expand ${j} in your sed, and $j without curly braces should work just fine before a dot.

```
sed -ie "3s/1e-11/$j./" ex.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 sed -ie '3s/1e-11/'"${j}"'./' ex.dat
```

Inside single quotes the shell doesn't replace variables by their values.